# How to Update specific slice of redux state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I seem to have hit a snag when updating state using redux and react-redux. When I update an individual slice of state, all of the others get removed. I know the answer to this will be simple but I can't figure it out and haven't found anything else online.

So to clarify, here's my reducer:

```
const initialState = {
        selectedLevel: null,
        selectedVenue: null,
        selectedUnitNumber: null,
        selectedUnitName: null,
        selectedYear: null
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    console.log('reducer: ', action);
    switch (action.type){
        case 'CHOOSE_LEVEL':
            return action.payload;
        case 'CHOOSE_VENUE':
            return action.payload;
        case 'CHOOSE_UNIT':
            return action.payload;
        case 'SHOW_COURSES':
            return action.payload;
    }

    return state;
}
```

And my combine reducer:

```
export default combineReducers({
    workshopSelection: WorkshopSelectReducer
});
```

So my initial state looks like this:

```
workshopSelection: {
    selectedLevel: null,
    selectedVenue: null,
    selectedUnitNumber: null,
    selectedUnitName: null,
    selectedYear: null
}
```

But when I use one of my action creators, for example:

```
export function chooseVenue(venue){
    return {
        type: 'CHOOSE_VENUE',
        payload: {
            selectedVenue: venue
        }
    }
}
```

I end up with state looking like this:

```
workshopSelection: {
    selectedVenue: 'London',
}
```

All of the rest of the state within this object that wasn't affected by this action creator has been completely wiped out. Instead, I just want all other entries to stay as they are with their original values - `null` in this example, or whatever other value has been assigned to them.

Hope that all makes sense.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically replacing one object (previous state) with another one (your payload, which is also an object).

In terms of standard JS, this would be the equlivalent of what your reducer does:

```
var action = {
    type: 'CHOOSE_VENUE',
    payload: {
        selectedVenue: venue
    }
};

var state = action.payload;
```

The simplest way to fix this would be using [Object spread properties](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread):

```
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type){
        case 'CHOOSE_LEVEL':
        case 'CHOOSE_VENUE':
        case 'CHOOSE_UNIT':
        case 'SHOW_COURSES':
            // Watch out, fall-through used here
            return {
                ...state,

                ...action.payload
            };
    }

    return state;
}
```

... but since this is still in experimental phase, you have to use some other way to clone previous properties and then override the new ones. A double `for ... in` loop could be a simple one:

```
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type){
        case 'CHOOSE_LEVEL':
        case 'CHOOSE_VENUE':
        case 'CHOOSE_UNIT':
        case 'SHOW_COURSES':
            // Watch out, fall-through used here
            const newState = {};

            // Note: No key-checks in this example
            for (let key in state) {
                newState[key] = state[key];
            }
            for (let key in action.payload) {
                newState[key] = action.payload[key];
            }

            return newState;
    }

    return state;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant - second option worked, thank you. Incidentally, I tried using spread operators, but it kept throwing a syntax error on the first `.` - is this because of their experimental nature? I am using webpack and babel to transpile my code and have used spread operators in other parts of the application with no issues, but for some reason on this one it didn't work. Any idea why this is - the ES6 syntax is much nicer so I'd like to use it wherever possible!

Comment: I assume it's because you've used Array spread, which is part of ES6 syntax. Object spread is something different, currently in Stage 2 (so unfortunately we will have to wait for it at least until ES2018). If you are using Babel 6, you need [Object rest spread plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/).

Comment: Of course - yes, the other times I've used it have been with arrays, not objects. Brilliant, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Keep your payload object as flat on actions creators as shown below...

```
export function chooseVenue(venue){
    return {
        type: 'CHOOSE_VENUE',
        selectedVenue: venue
    }
}
```

and modify your reducer as below (given example is for updating the  venue, do the same for other cases too...)

```
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    let newState = Object.assign({}, state); // Take copy of the old state
    switch (action.type){
        case 'CHOOSE_LEVEL':
        case 'CHOOSE_VENUE':
               newState.selectedVenue = action.selectedVenue; // mutate the newState with payload
               break;
        case 'CHOOSE_UNIT':
        case 'SHOW_COURSES':
        default :
           return newState;   
    }

    return newState; // Returns the newState;
}
```